Which residue to pick from infinitely many?
If I am solving a real integral with complex analysis with the residue theorem and the function to integrate has some thing like
$$\sec(\phi) = \frac{2}{e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}}$$
Where the residues are here.
Which one do I pick out of the infinitely many? In general, which residue(s) do we pick if there are infinitely many? I am new to this kind of math so please forgive me if it sounds basic or obvious.
Edit:
Would this be the right contour? I am responding to the answer.

The integral in question is
$$\int_{0}^{\arctan(x_0/x_1)} \tan \left(\frac{ab}{5}\sec(\phi)\right)d\phi$$

Could you edit into your question which definite integral you'd like to evaluate? Our advice will be very sensitive to specifics. The residue theorem is a rather subtle tool.

@J.G. I have added it

What are $x_0$ and $x_1$?

@RobertIsrael just general variables that can take on a value. The idea is that you don't know what value they will have in advance, so just leave them as variables.

Let $\arctan(x_0/x_1) = X$ and $ab/c = k$, so you want $\int_0^X \tan(k \sec(\phi)); d\phi$.  I'll assume $X$ and $k$ are positive. If $X \ge \arccos(2k/\pi)$ the integral  diverges.  Otherwise, your integral is an antiderivative of $\tan(k \sec(X))$.  Residues give you no help with this.  The antiderivative is not an elementary function.

Can you post your full answer for that please? @RobertIsrael It looks interesting.

@RobertIsrael I forgot to add the $5$ in the denominator. Please see my integral again. Thanks.

Let $\arctan(x_0/x_1)=X$ and $ab/5=k$, so you want $$
\int_0^X \tan(k \sec(\phi))d\phi$$ I'll assume $X$ and $k$ are positive. If $X\ge \arccos(2k/\pi)$ the integral diverges. Otherwise, your integral is an antiderivative of $\tan(k \sec(X))$. Residues give you no help with this. The antiderivative is not an elementary function, which can be proven using the Risch-Norman algorithm as implemented in many Computer Algebra systems.

Just to clarify: If $X \lt \arccos(2k/\pi)$ then the integral evaluates to
$$\tan(k \sec(X))$$??

@Mathaholic that is not what Robert said. It was said that the integral would be an antidote of what you wrote

@FShrike Antiderivative, not "antidote".  It just means that if $F(X) = \int_0^X \tan(k \sec(\phi)); d\phi$, then $\dfrac{d}{dX} F(X) = \tan(k \sec(X))$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

@RobertIsrael Yes, I know what antiderivative means. Unfortunately my new phone’s autocorrect doesn’t.

@FShrike Yes, I thought you knew.  My comment was aimed at the OP, who apparently did not know.

@RobertIsrael I was trying to clarify your answer as I do know what the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is. But do we know what the integral will evaluate to? Also, why do we compare $X$ to $\arccos \left(2k/\pi \right)$ and not something else?


The integral is not an elementary function.  It's possible, but very unlikely, that it has an expression in terms of some "named" special functions.
Because when $X = \arccos(2k/\pi)$, $k \sec(X) = \pi/2$, so $\tan(k \sec(X))$ blows up there.


It depends on the contour!
If $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Bbb C$ is a closed continuous curve whose image avoids all the poles of $\sec$, then: $$\oint_\gamma\sec=2\pi i\cdot\sum_{p\in\text{ all poles!}}I(\gamma;p)\cdot\mathrm{Res}(\sec;p)$$
And only those poles for whom $I(\gamma;p)\neq0$ will be relevant (intuitively, only the poles which are enclosed by $\gamma$, which tends to be geometrically clear, contribute to the integral). If you're dealing with some infinite contour, then really you're taking integrals over a family of finite contours, and you'd correspondingly have to take a limit on the series on the right hand side.
This can be made more precise and straightforward when $\gamma$ is moreover a (nonconstant) simple curve; then we can formally declare: $$\oint_{\gamma}\sec=(\pm)2\pi i\cdot\sum_{p\text{ a pole inside the curve }}\mathrm{Res}(\sec;p)$$Where the sign $\pm$ comes from the orientation of $\gamma$. So, truly, only the poles inside $\gamma$ would matter.

I have edited my question with the contour in question. Is that the right one or something else is needed?

I have added the integral to be evaluated into my question

@Mathaholic The question you wanted to have an answer to (how to use complex analysis to evaluate this integral) and the question you actually asked are different! There is no "right contour", my answer just gives an answer to your original question: when applying the residue theorem, which residues matter?
